# How to search via elasticsearch in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, elasticsearch

I have indexed data from firebase via elasticSearch .
And Its Working Properly .

Now I am Searching data via firebase below cloud function :

```
exports.searchIt = functions.database.ref('/search/{key}')
                .onUpdate(event => {

                    let key=event.params.key;

                    let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;

                    const esClient = new elastic.Client({
                      host: 'http://35.198.221.164',
                      log: 'error'
                    });

                    console.log('client Created');

                    let searchBody = {
                        size: 20,
                        from: 0,
                        query: {
                          match_all: {}
                        }
                      };


                    esClient.search({index: 'offers', body: searchBody})
                    .then(results => {
                        console.log('Successfully Entered');
                        results.hits.hits.forEach(
                          (hit, index) => console.log(hit)
                        )
                      })
                      .catch(console.error);

                });
```

But this gives error below :

> textPayload:  "{ Error: Not Found at respond
>   (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:307:15) at
>   checkRespForFailure
>   (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:266:7) at
>   HttpConnector.
>   (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:159:7)
>   at IncomingMessage.bound
>   (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
>   at emitNone (events.js:91:20) at IncomingMessage.emit
>   (events.js:185:7) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12) at
>   _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)

And on changing host to any other it still create client.

Why is this happening?

Comment: this is not related to android

Comment: I would suggest to not post your actual ip!

Comment: Can you post the output of running `curl -XGET http://<your ip>/_search`? (From the same machine where the node.js code is failing.)

Comment: Error Solved. I forgotten to add "/elasticsearch"  to host.

Comment: Formatted error as quote. Removed Android tag.